# Singleton or React Context to access data access layer functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React what’s the best approach to pass around an instantiated class that provides access to backend data functions (eg getXX, createXx).  In terms of:

A) singleton
B) react context

Does React Context provide some benefit?  If using React Context where would you instantiate the class and add it to the Context?

Note: was intending to define data access class as an interface, then could have Dev and Prod implementations I could manually swap in/out.

Comment: when you said **what’s the best approach to pass around an instantiated class that provides access to backend data functions** did you mean the best way to fetch and post data from an Api ?

Comment: Assume there is a class with data access layer calls to be used. Then the best way to instantiate this and use it within your React app.

Comment: Background: I want to abstract the backend call code out. In fact define an interface for it for the a React app to use. Then can have more than one implementation (have a test one for development).  Assuming this is done via an interface and implementing this interface, what is then the best way to instantiate this helper and pass it around my React app

Comment: **The React Context API** produce global variables that can be passed   within your React app . And there is some alternative of react context like (redux ...) . you can check how it works [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an absolute answer to this, but my thoughts are that you should have it as react context **only if it depends on react state**.

In other words, if you want the behavior of the API call to function differently when you're in this or that particular state, then having it as context makes sense. If it's independent of that, there's no harm in having it be a singleton.

Comment: This is what I’ve been wondering.  Singletons ok then in this case then?  I mean noting singleton is referred to as an anti-pattern sometimes, I’m not sure what the alternative would be.

Comment: Actually you’d said it’s ok…(thanks)

Comment: It's good you're thinking about this, and trying to avoid anti-patterns. I think the anti-pattern is more global state than singletons themselves-- if you're just using a wrapper that makes api calls, it's not a big deal. If that wrapper has complicated state that varies over time, then you'd want to use some more state management like redux.

Comment: I don't think there's really a fixed answer to this, it depends a lot on context. If you find yourself doing hacky things with the singleton or fighting with React, then you can always move it into context later if that works better.